# Running TestNG through commadline ubuntu not working

Tags: selenium, testng, ubuntu-16.04

When tried to run the testNg through commandline in ubuntu it throws the

```
java –cp "bin:/home/john/selenium-lib/*" org.testng.TestNG src/testing.xml

Error: Could not find or load main class –cp
```

- src/TestCase */

  package Test;

  ```
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class TestCase {
      String message = "Hello World";


         @Test
         public void testPrintMessage() {
             System.out.println("Invoked testString " + message);

         }
   }
  ```

  src/testing.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you perhaps did a copy paste due to which `-` (hyphen) is being read as a special character `–`. Please try again by typing `-cp` (hyphen `cp`)

Comment: Krishnan Mahadevan thanks a lots that was it while copy/paste it was treating hyphen(-)  as special character. My bad I missed that